# including php into html loading first at the wrong place of the website

Tags: php, html

I put a php form into my html file, changed the file from index.html to index.php. Website is loading, form is working. However Website loads first where the form Begins and not at the Header. Is there any command how I can force the Website to load at the Header first?

Thanky, appreciate any help!

Comment: Post your code so we can see what is happening.

Comment: this seem not clair , can you explain more or show the code and explain the expected results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your PHP code is at the top of the page.

Is your page structured like

```
<?php
 form
?>
<html>
<head>
```

If so, you need to move the PHP code down in to the main body section where you want the form to appear.

```
<html>
<head>
head stuff
</head>
<body>
fjdkdfjkfdj
dfkjkjfljfdk

<?php>
   form
</php?

fjdkfdjd
footer text
</bod>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey thanks. However my php code is exactly down in the main body section where it should appear. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code, or make another simple page demonstrating this? At least we can see if there are any errors in your code, or if it something to do with your setup.